# Where did the "hide the toolbar" thingy go on OS X Lion?

Tags: macos

On OS X Snow Leopard, there was an option to hide the toolbar in many applications, such as 
[image: toolbar thingy]

but I don't have that option on Lion anymore[image: lion macvim]

This isn't MacVim specific issue, I don't see it in Adium and many other applications too. Did the button just disappear? Is there any way to show ita again?

Comment: It was called the "lozenge"

Answer (score 6):

I don't think there's a way to make the toolbar capsule widget thingy show up again.

However, if you want to hide the toolbar, you can right-click on the empty toolbar area and choose the "Hide Toolbar" option:

[image]

You can also go to the View menu and choose "Hide Toolbar" from there.  It may also have a keyboard shortcut of <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>opt</kbd>-<kbd>t</kbd>.

Answer (score 3):

Right click and "Hide Toolbar" works for most apps. I couldn't get it to work with MacVim but this should:

Add the following to your .vimrc:

```
if has("gui_running")
    set guioptions=egmrt
endif
```

test it out via:

```
:set guioptions=egmrt
```